# SQL - Trigger for Audit of all Columns, accounting for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been learning about triggers and I've read a lot and I'm a bit confused on accounting for multiple rows.  If I have something like the following pared down example, does this account for multiple rows?

If so, is there a better / shorter way to do it?  I have to do a UNION per column in the table.

This enables me to run 1 insert for all columns that would be changed, but I'm not sure how well that handles multiple rows or if that is the cleanest way to do it (easily maintainable for others.)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.t_Audit
    (
        TableName
      , ColumnName
      , OLD_Value
      , NEW_Value
    )
SELECT  't_Staff'
      , 'FullName'
      , CAST(d.FullName AS VARCHAR)
      , CAST(i.FullName AS VARCHAR)
FROM    Inserted  i
FULL JOIN Deleted d ON d.PersonName = i.PersonName
WHERE   dbo.f_CompareValues(d.FullName, i.FullName) = 0  /*If = or null then 1*/
UNION
SELECT  't_Staff'
      , 'Email'
      , CAST(d.Email AS VARCHAR)
      , CAST(i.Email AS VARCHAR)
FROM    Inserted  i
FULL JOIN Deleted d ON d.EmpEmail = i.EmpEmail
WHERE   dbo.f_CompareValues(d.EmailAddress, i.EmailAddress) = 0  /*If = or null then 1*/
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: Sql-Server (tsql)

Comment: Your trigger does handles multiple rows. But you probably also want to include the `primary key` value of the table in the `t_Audit`